# Why is the voltage in the resistor different from what is recorded in the oscilloscope and multimeter?

Tags: resistors, multisim

I made a halfwave rectifier circuit in Multisim.

How is it possible that the voltage on the resistor is Vrms (Resistor) = 10.562V while on the oscilloscope the Vpeak = 33.264V?

Isn't the Vpeak on the resistor supposed to be (10.562V)(√2) = 14.94V? How is it possible that the voltage in the diode is Vrms (Diode) = 13.475V, when its forward voltage drop is 1.2V?

[image]

Comment: The √2 factor only applies to sine waves. For the waveform shown here, Vrms is NOT Vpeak/√2.

Answer (score 3):

Peak voltage measured on the oscilloscope is 33.264V.
A **DC** voltmeter measures the same potential difference and reports 10.562V. This is an average of the oscilloscope waveform. Not RMS, but **average**.

What is the average of a half-wave whose peak is 33.264V?
Average of one-half cycle is \${2\over{\pi}} \times V_p\$, which is 21.176V.
For the next half cycle, the average is zero, because the diode doesn't conduct. These alternating half-cycles repeat.
The average value of those two half cycles is \${21.176\over2} + {0\over2}\$ which is 10.588V.

---

Why does the DC voltmeter report less? (10.562V vs. 10.588V)
Those two half cycles are not *exactly* half, since the diode has a small forward drop. The first half cycle while the diode conducts is slightly shorter than the second half cycle.

Comment: I have a follow up question, [my circuit in multisim](https://imgur.com/a/T0UA2zQ), why does the oscilloscope reports a negative wave when the diode is in forward bias? Did I miss something? Thank you for your response, I very much appreciate it.

Comment: First, there is a major error in *that* circuit...Look how Ch.A "-" input connects, then look how Ch.B "-" input connects. In a real oscilloscope, these inputs are both connected to GND inside the oscilloscope. Had this been a breadboard, smoke would ensue because the oscilloscope GND shorts out the resistor. Apparently, this Multisim virtual oscilloscope has completely isolated Ch.A & Ch.B input channels, unlike most *real* 'scopes....

Comment: Why show -ve voltage? When conducting, the diode should cause the oscilloscope display to peak at about +0.6V, with diode's anode more +ve than its cathode. While *not conducting*, the diode anode must be a more negative voltage than its cathode, and the anode voltage shows a negative-going swing. You might consider the diode in this state as an open-circuit.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it now. Thank you for your time. Cheers!